# Schedule script on weekday but not weekend, run on Friday if weekend

Tags: shell, cron

I want to schedule a shell script to run on the 17th of every month only if the 17th is a weekday. However if the 17th falls on a weekend, I want the script to be run on the Friday before (eg if 17th is a Saturday, I would like to run the script on 16th Friday or if 17th is a Sunday I would like to run the script on 15th Friday) . I have explored cron but I am not sure this will work

```
00 08 17 * 1-5 <script to be run>
```

I believe this will only run the script on 17th if its a weekday, I guess it will not run if its a weekend.

How can I run the script on Friday before if the 17th of the Month is a weekend?

Comment: No, [00 08 17 * 1-5](https://crontab.guru/#00_08_17_*_1-5) will run on the 17th *and* on every weekday. Your schedule isn't supported by cron. You'd need to combine a cron schedule that runs every Friday with additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cronjob, you must use 2 crons:
1. Run every 17th in weekday as your setting:

```
00 08 17 * 1-5 <script to be run>
```

2. Run every Friday and execute if next Sartuday/Sunday is 17th:

```
00 08 * * 5 CURR=$(date) && NEXT_SAR=$(date -d "$CURR 24 hours" +'%d') && NEXT_SUN=$(date -d "$CURR 48 hours" +'%d') && [[ "$NEXT_SAR" == "17" || "$NEXT_SUN" == "17" ]] && <script to be run> || echo 'Do not run'
```

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

@TuanBA & @Christian Pekeler Thank you both for your suggestions.

I have managed to get the below to work. Please suggest if there is a better way this can be achieved.

This script will run if the 15th or 16th is a Friday or if 17th is a weekday and will exit if it does not match any of the dates. I will be using cron to schedule it to run on 15th 16th and 17th.

```
#!/bin/bash


dom=`(date +%d)`
dow=`(date +%u)`


if [ $dom -eq 15 ] && [ $dow -eq 5 ]
then
bin/sh /This/is/thepath/tothescript/test.sh

elif
[ $dom -eq 16 ] && [ $dow -eq 5 ]
then
bin/sh /This/is/thepath/tothescript/test.sh

elif

[ $dom -eq 17 ] && [ $dow -le 5 ]
then
bin/sh /This/is/thepath/tothescript/test.sh

else

exit

fi
```